# Bootstrap: Why do my input box and button have gap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please check my code at http://jsfiddle.net/TccN5/.

It has a gap between the input text box and the button on the right. For the very same markup on [Bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) the input box and the button has a nice tight fit with no gap.

Why do I have the gap?

[image: My Version]

[image: Bootstrap Version]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have extra `whitespace character`s between `button` and `input` elements. Place `button` tag immediately after `input` element:

```
<input type="text" /><button class="btn" type="button">Any</button>
```

[**DEMO1**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qEZd/1/)

Or alternatively, apply this css styles:

```
​.input-append{
    font-size:0;
}​
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qEZd/)

Comment: Awesome. I would have never figured that out.

Comment: I totally forgot that these are inline elements and so whitespace's dimension would matter.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why that is, but this is how i fixed it. maybe you got some of your own css conflicting with the text field.

here's the jsfiddle with the fix http://jsfiddle.net/TccN5/2/

I just added

```
     style="margin-right:-4px"
```

to your

```
     <input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `input-prepend` and `input-append`

```
<div class="btn-group input-prepend input-append">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Prev">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Next">
<div>
```